# upload multiple csv from google cloud to bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I need to upload multiple CSV files from my google bucket. Tried pointing to the bucket when creating the dataset, but i received an error. also tried

```
gsutil load <projectID:dataset.table> gs://mybucket
```

it didn't work.

I need to upload multiple files at a time as my total data is 2-3 TB and there is a large number of files

Comment: bq load --autodetect --noreplace --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 [my-dataset].[my-table] gs://[my-bucket]/[my-folder]/*

Answer (score 4):

You're close. Google Cloud Storage uses gsutil, but BigQuery's command-line utility is "bq". The command you're looking for is `bq load <table> gs://mybucket/file.csv`.

bq's documentation is over here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool